# Limit execution time of shell_script in PHP

Tags: php, linux, shell, shell-exec

I am calling a shell script in Linux using a PHP script, I do the following:

```
shell_exec('./shell_script.sh');
```

after this the PHP script continues on.. All this works as expected.

However, sometimes the shell_script doesn't finish executing for whatever reason, so here is the question:

How can I terminate the shell_script.sh after being executed for x amount of time?
Should this be dealt with in PHP itself somehow (dont think that's possible in this instance) or should it be done in the .sh itself?

So just after the:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

at the beginning of the .sh, is there something I can put for it to terminate if execution time exceeds say 20 seconds perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you can do it in php, and there may exist better solutions in bash, but this is what you could do:

This is the line you can put immediately after `#!/bin/bash` to kill the current script after 20 seconds:

```
(sleep 20 && kill $$) &
```

bash replaces $$ with the pid of the current script.

Comment: To make it work in the same script you can start a subshell: `( sleep 20 && kill $$ ) &`

Comment: yeah, that works. I thought I had tried exactly that, but apparently I haven't because now it works... I'll edit my answer

Comment: Doesn't appear to work entirely as it cant get the right pid? e.g. line 3: kill: (32613) - No such process

Comment: Also the problem with this approach is that the script always takes 20seconds to die now, instead of dying after say 8 seconds if completed first.... hmmmm.

Comment: @hsmoore.com "No such process" happens when the parent process exits before `sleep` finishes. You can get rid of the message by redirect the stderr of the subshell to `/dev/null`. To make the script die sooner you can cancel the timer by storing the PID and killing it later. In fact, I'll add an answer with a code sample...

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
# start timer
( sleep $TIMEOUT ; kill $$ ) 2>/dev/null &
TIMER_PID=$!

# "payload"
echo hello

# cancel timer
kill $TIMER_PID
```

YMMV though, in my tests the part that is supposed to cancel the timer sometimes doesn't kill `sleep` and the program waits until the timeout finishes.

Comment: I've tried this approach and it doesn't quite work, because it doesn't kill the sub processes, only the main shell_script. The shell_script basically uses xvfb-run to run a x app. so essentially the kill $TIMER_PID should also kill all the sub processes of the bash. Make sense?